# How to pass value button to another page which is a popup form by alert function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, iframe, magnific-popup

I want to pass value **register** at button tag to the another page (popup form). So that, when user click the button and popup form will appear, when user want to fill up the form, they know by **alert function** which form they fill up. How to pass the value by using jquery into the another page which is popup form.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnContact').magnificPopup({
      items: {
        src: '**a link..**'
      },
      type: 'iframe'
    });
  });
</script>
<section class="singlecol nosiblings" role="main">

  <br />
  <button name="btnContact" class="btn btn-primary downloadDirect" id="btnContact" value="**register**">Contact Us</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `data-formname="Register"` attribute to the button, and use jQuery .data('formname') to get the value of 'Register'. So the complete code will look like this:
 `var text = $('button').data('formname');`

I hope that helps